# my windows XP isn't starting on VirtualBox

Tags: windows-xp, virtualbox

It just says this every time:

```
Failed to open a session for the virtual machine Windows XP.

Not in a hypervisor partition (HVP=0) (VERR_NEM_NOT_AVAILABLE).

VT-x is disabled in the BIOS for all CPU modes (VERR_VMX_MSR_ALL_VMX_DISABLED).

Result Code: E_FAIL (0x80004005)
Component: ConsoleWrap
Interface: IConsole {872da645-4a9b-1727-bee2-5585105b9eed}
```

Help me please.

Comment: Is it a 32-bit or 64-bit install of Windows XP?

Comment: So, the problem is not actually that Windows isn’t starting. It’s that the VM isn’t starting, which is something different entirely.

Comment: Please edit your question to provide more details. Such as what is the make and model of the host machine you are running VirtualBox on. Also, what OS is running VirtualBox: Windows? Linux? macOS? What version on the OS is running as well.

Comment: If VBOX is running then XP 32-bit should run. Try installing XP again.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the error
"VT-x is disabled in the BIOS for all CPU modes"
is that virtualization is not enabled in your Windows computer.

Many Windows computers have the virtualization disabled by default
at the BIOS level and it needs to be enabled to set up a new virtual machine. If your computer is relatively old, it may not have this
option at all.

Solution : Enter the BIOS and search for a VT-x option to be enabled.
It may have other names, depending on your BIOS version.

For more information, let us know the model of your computer and
your BIOS version.

The following article may also help with detailed instructions
and screenshots:
[How to Enable Vt-x in BIOS Security Settings in Intel Processors For Android Studio?](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-enable-vt-x-in-bios-security-settings-in-intel-processors-for-android-studio/)